# Query Neo4j and return found Nodes with Net Driver in WPF App

Tags: c#, wpf, neo4j

I like to search in my neo4j db with a string and get all Nodes as results back to handle them later in an AutosuggestBox.

First throw was to bring up a connection and query then the db to return my Nodes.

Now Im having trouble to return each found Node with its attribute called Name if its match, im always getting strange results in my messagebaox where I try to check my returned Nodes:

```
        private static async Task<List<string>> GetSuggestionsFromNeoAsync(string currentInput) {

            IDriver driver = GraphDatabase.Driver("bolt://localhost:7687", AuthTokens.Basic("neo4j", "neo4j"));
            IAsyncSession session = driver.AsyncSession(o => o.WithDatabase("neo4j"));

            var query2Neo = "Match (p:Person { Name:'" + currentInput + "'}) RETURN p.samAccountName as name";

            IResultCursor cursor = await session.RunAsync(query2Neo);
            List<string> people = await cursor.ToListAsync(record => record["Name"].As<string>());

            await cursor.ConsumeAsync();

            await driver.CloseAsync();
            return people;
    }
```

Ive tryed to setup that Query to get Reults like from: https://github.com/neo4j/neo4j-dotnet-driver
But most exmaples are for neo4j v3 with the Client.

thank you and best regards

update with working code:

```
        private static async Task ShowResultsAsync()
    {
        var found = await GetSuggestionsFromNeoAsync("Name");
        if (found.Count > 0)
        {
            //enumerate the inner list
            foreach (var item in found)
            {
                //output the actual item
                MessageBox.Show("Person found Entry: " + item);
            }
        }
        else {
            MessageBox.Show("Person not found");

        }

    }
```

Comment: You have to await the method call: `var found = await GetSuggestionsFromNeoAsync("Name");` Otherwise the `found` variable will get a `Task<List<string>>` instead of a `List<string>`. Make yourself familiar with [async/await](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/async/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`GetSuggestionsFromNeoAsync` is an asynchronous method. This mean that it will return when it hits an `await` and execute the remainder of the method when the `Task` being awaited has completed.

So when you call `GetSuggestionsFromNeoAsync` from your `showREsults` method, it runs synchronously until the `IResultCursor cursor = await session.RunAsync(query2Neo)` line and then returns, whereupon the `MessageBox` is shown. Please refer to the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/async/task-asynchronous-programming-model) for more information about what happens in an async method.

If you want to display the `MessageBox` when the `GetSuggestionsFromNeoAsync` has completed, you should await the async method. For you to be able to do this, you need to add the `async` keyword to the signature of the `showREsults` method. You should also change its return type to `Task` and add the *Async suffix to its name:

```
private static async Task ShowResultsAsync()
{
    var found = await GetSuggestionsFromNeoAsync("Name");
    MessageBox.Show("Person found Entry: " + found.Name);
}
```